# Identifying event of Imap/smtp after what I can fire push notification?

Tags: php, android, ios, smtp, imap

I have configured exim-dovecot-***webclient on cent-os for setting up an email application, wrote some web services in php for my mobile application need and now working on mobile application that will receive push notifications from server. I want to trigger/broadcast push notification to mobile application when email arrives. Although, I know all the procedure for sending a push notification to mobile device but unable to find the event/flag after what I can fire the notification.